# Richardson extrapolation - deriving methods for forward difference

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, approximation-theory, finite-differences

I am rather stuck on a question from a textbook that I am practicing from which goes as follows:

The forward difference formula can be expressed as $$f'(x_{0}) = \frac{1}{h}[f(x_{0} + h) - f(x_{0})] - \frac{h}{2}f^{2}(x_{0}) - \frac{h^{2}}{6}f^{3}(x_{0}) + O(h^{3})$$

Use extrapolation to derive an $O(h^{3})$ formula for $f'(x_{0})$. Basically the textbook has an answer that is given by $$f'(x_{0}) = \frac{1}{12h}[f(x_{0} + 4h) - 12f(x_{0} + 2h) + 32f(x_{0} + h) - 21f(x_{0})]$$ which is $O(h^{3})$.

Would someone mind explaining how this answer was arrived upon ? I arrived at a different answer where instead of using an expansion of points, I shrunk the it by using the points $(x_{0} + h/4,f(x_{0} + h/4)),(x_{0} + h/2,f(x_{0} + h/2)),(x_{0} + h,f(x_{0} + h))$ which gave me different coefficients and I am not sure if this is correct.

Also it would be nice if someone could explain when it is the case that when should reduce the side of the stepsize, h, as opposed to expanding it. The textbook covers a case of richardson extrapolation by reducing $h$ but I am slightly confused when to make the decision.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you expand the terms of the rhs as Taylor series around $h=0$, you have $$f(x+4h)=f(x)+4 h f'(x)+8 h^2 f''(x)+\frac{32}{3} h^3 f^{(3)}(x)+\frac{32}{3} h^4
   f^{(4)}(x)+O\left(h^5\right)$$ $$f(x+2h)=f(x)+2 h f'(x)+2 h^2 f''(x)+\frac{4}{3} h^3 f^{(3)}(x)+\frac{2}{3} h^4
   f^{(4)}(x)+O\left(h^5\right)$$ $$f(x+h)=f(x)+h f'(x)+\frac{1}{2} h^2 f''(x)+\frac{1}{6} h^3 f^{(3)}(x)+\frac{1}{24} h^4
   f^{(4)}(x)+O\left(h^5\right)$$ Combining all of the above gives $$f(x + 4h) - 12f(x + 2h) + 32f(x + h) - 21f(x)=12 h f'(x)+4 h^4 f^{(4)}(x)+O\left(h^5\right)$$ Now, let us do the same with your data points $$f(x+\frac h4)=f(x)+\frac{1}{4} h f'(x)+\frac{1}{32} h^2 f''(x)+\frac{1}{384} h^3
   f^{(3)}(x)+\frac{h^4 f^{(4)}(x)}{6144}+O\left(h^5\right)$$ $$f(x+\frac h2)=f(x)+\frac{1}{2} h f'(x)+\frac{1}{8} h^2 f''(x)+\frac{1}{48} h^3
   f^{(3)}(x)+\frac{1}{384} h^4 f^{(4)}(x)+O\left(h^5\right)$$ $$f(x+h)=f(x)+h f'(x)+\frac{1}{2} h^2 f''(x)+\frac{1}{6} h^3 f^{(3)}(x)+\frac{1}{24} h^4
   f^{(4)}(x)+O\left(h^5\right)$$ Now write $$F=af(x+\frac h4)+bf(x+\frac h2)+cf(x+h)+df(x)$$ and cancels as many terms as you can (you must set equal to $1$ the coefficient of $f'(x)$); this gives $$a+b+c+d=0$$ $$a+2b+4c=4$$ $$a+4b+16c=0$$ $$a+8b+64c=0$$ and the solutions are $$a=\frac{32}3\qquad b=-4\qquad c=\frac 13 \qquad d=-7$$ which gives $$F=h f'(x)+\frac{1}{192} h^4 f^{(4)}(x)+O\left(h^5\right)$$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, the way you arrived at the answer is much more easier to understand and less prone to errors which I will follow from now on.

Comment: You are very welcome ! In any manner, this is the way to establish the formula for any number of selected data points.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, my brain is just not clicking for the numerical methods course I am taking and some concepts are difficult for me to get a full grasp of especially after spending a long time on it (hopefully I may be able to consult your expertise as I am trying to get as much practice as possible). By the way, as a side note to the answer with respect to the first part, did you determine the coefficients for the end result in a similar manner as the way you described for the data points that I used?

Comment: Whenever you want, you will be welcome ! The method is always the same and applies to the derivative of any order. Don't hesitate to contact me. If I can be of any help, it will be my pleasure.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness Claude, may I ask you a question about numerical approximations for differential equations ?  I am hoping to look for your guidance in the following post http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1719838/numerical-approximation-for-pde . Could you provide some advice please on this topic ? I have been trying my best going through other textbooks but am unable to find something similar to my PDE (perhaps my knowledge of PDE is quite weak) but my professor quite a hard project for a course I am keenly trying to catch up on. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: @PutsandCalls. I am sorry ! I am very, very, very bad with PDE's.

Comment: Not at all! I very appreciate your response